# Angular set dropdown select option as default selected before iteration

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a select dropdown and I iterate the options from a list. I am trying to set as selected a separate option (as a default), in case of user is not selecting a value.

Here is how I am trying to implement that:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="book.pageLayout">
    <option [value]="0" [attr.selected]="book.defaultLayoutId === null">No Default Layout</option>
    <option *ngFor="let l of availableLayouts"
            [value]="l.id"
            [attr.selected]="book.pageLayout == l.id">
      {{l?.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

I also tried:

```
<option [value]="0" selected="selected">No Default Layout</option>
```

and even:

```
<option [value]="0" selected="1==1">No Default Layout</option>
```

but none of the above worked.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 9):

Attribute selected will not help much if you are using ngModel then you can do easily with setting default value to the defined model.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="book.pageLayout">
  <option value="">No Default Layout</option>
  <option *ngFor="let l of availableLayouts" [value]="l.id">
    {{l?.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Then inside component.ts

```
public book: any = {
   pageLayout: ''
}
```

**Edit**

To set default option we need to set pageLayout value to id instead of empty string.

```
public book: any = {
   pageLayout: 1
}

public availableLayouts: any = [
  {
    name: "One",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Two",
    id: 2
  }
]
```

Comment: This is an option indeed. Not the one I finally used, but thank you for helping out.

Comment: What should be default pageLayout? Object containing id parameter or only id? Could you please edit your example with some meaningful default value?

Comment: @shemekh should be id to set default.

Comment: @GeorgeGeorge what did you ene up using , because i am using service mapping <select [(ngModel)]="demoService.pageLayout">

Comment: making value="" as value ="null" will do the job also

Answer (score 5):

You can use FormControl from Angular Reactive Form.It is easy.
[Angular Docs About Reactive Form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)
You need to import `reactive form` to you module

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // other imports ...
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Than you need to create FormControl in you component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-name-editor',
  templateUrl: './name-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./name-editor.component.css']
})
export class NameEditorComponent {
  name = new FormControl('');
}
```

After this you need to set Form control to your element `select` in html

```
<select [formControl]="name">
  <option value="null">No Default Layout</option>
  <option *ngFor="let l of availableLayouts" [value]="l.id">
    {{l?.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

If you need default value of select you must create formControl with value for example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-name-editor',
  templateUrl: './name-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./name-editor.component.css']
})
export class NameEditorComponent {
  name = new FormControl(null);
}

///(you can pass any to new FormControl(0), or new FormControl(false), new FormControl('string'))
```

In this case default value for select will be null.And options with value null will be selected in dropdawn.

In you case `new FormControl(0)` as default value.

Comment: Also <option [value]="0" [attr.selected]="book.defaultLayoutId === null">No Default Layout</option> 0 dont equal to nul; 0 !== null;

Comment: <option [value]="null" selected>No Default Layout</option>  ithink you can try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<option [value]="undefined" selected>No Default Layout</option>`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

try code:

```
this.fullNamePresentors = this.programInfo1.filter(item => item.time >  this.fulltextDate);
```

and:

```
  <select class="form-control" id="marasemaat" style="margin-top: 10%;font-size: 13px;" [(ngModel)]="fullNamePresentors" [formControl]="stateControl"  
    (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let char of programInfo1;let i = index;"  onclick="currentSlide(9,false)" value={{char.id}}>{{char.title + " "}}  ----> {{char.name + " "+ char.family }} ---- > {{(char.time.split('T', 2)[1]).split(':',2)}}</option>

  </select>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

`ng-selected="selected"`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: This is for old version angular 1.